Issue with mdb-tools and empty string date time fields
I'm have a .mdb access database with [table1] with [field1] as a datetime type.
I use php pdo and mdb-tools to access the database.
I use php strototime function to build sql statements to get rows that are past a certain date.  It works well.
It does not work well when someone updates the datetime field in those rows with '' or vbNULL to remove the datetime data.  After that happens, the query still includes those rows as if empty string or null is greater than the strototime date.
I cannot use "field1 IS NOT NULL" in mdb-tools WHERE statement and "field1 <> '' " does not seem to work correctly either.
The access hex() function of a blank field1 returned 0
What are some php or sql work arounds for this issue?

Please give us details about why you can't use WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL ... does Access complain about it?  Or is there some other reason?

IS NOT NULL doesn't seem to be an mdbtools operator:
SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD1 <> '' AND FIELD1 IS NOT NULL AND FIELD1 > 17275860000;
+------------+--------------------+
|FIELD1                |
+------------+--------------------+
Calling mdb_test_sarg on unknown operator.  Add code to mdb_test_double() for operator 11
Calling mdb_test_sarg on unknown operator.  Add code to mdb_test_double() for operator 11
Calling mdb_test_sarg on unknown operator.  Add code to mdb_test_double() for operator 11
+------------+--------------------+
No Rows retrieved

Suggest you try this simpler query to double-check whether IS NOT NULL is supported under mdbtools: SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD1 IS NOT NULL  Do you get  reasonable results or none at all?

Have you tested your original query within Access itself?  I wonder how it evaluates 17275860000 as a Date/Time value.

IS NOT NULL doesn't seem to be a valid operator for mdb-tools - it gives the same operator error message above when used alone and no results.  obviously, IS NOT NULL operator works in access.

testing original query with access itself gives an overflow error...pretty certain because access doesn't use unix timestamps to store the data.... you might be on something though...looking at this deeper
